# Adding new parameters to ARM template parameters file

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have an original azure deployment that was created with original template parameters file.
I needed to change some logic at the template file and hence I needed to add some new extra parameters to the parameters file.
But when I tried to redeploy it I encountered the following error:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 9:43:19 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation
> failed: 'The template parameters 'SecondaryServiceFabricClusterName, shouldDeployNewCluster' in the parameters file
> are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The
> only supported parameters for this template are .....

Anyone have an idea what is the problem and how I should do it properly?

P.S - this procedure is done via the Azure command line

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same issue here : https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/3551

Happens when the parameters specified in the `azuredeploy.parameters.json` (ARM template parameters file) and the `azuredeploy.json` ARM template file have a mismatch. (Ps : make sure you also double check each param for spelling errors, types etc.)

`'SecondaryServiceFabricClusterName, shouldDeployNewCluster' in the parameters file are not valid` << check inside the `parameters` section of your ARM template if these 2 parameters are specified or used.

If you aren't using those parameters in your template, then remove them from your parameters file azuredeploy.parameters.json and it should fix the issue.

But alternatively if you want to keep them, then add them to the `parameters` section of your `azuredeploy.json` ARM template file